# VB ASP Array prevent multi reading

Tags: asp.net, arrays, sql-server, vb.net

[image]

This is my 'code':

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim arrName As New ArrayList()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=GradingSystemSample;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()

        cmd.CommandText = "select numb FROM Table2  "
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            While rdr.Read

                arrName.Add(rdr("numb"))
                For Each pno As String In arrName
                    MsgBox(pno)
                Next

            End While

        End If
End sub
```

**I want my output to be:**
639057318820
639355514108
639056784959

**but my code output is:**
639057318820
639057318820
639355514108
639057318820
639355514108
639056784959

it seems like my code is reading is reading from the indexes 0 before reading the next index. help me guys?

Comment: btw the numbers comes from my database . i attach the images here but i think it does not show .

Comment: You are displaying the message box in a loop inside the read loop. Read 1, print 1, Read #2, print 1 and 2, read #3, print 1,2,3

Comment: so how to fix that sir ?

Comment: whats wrong with my code sir ?

Comment: You do know that the words "inside" and "outside" don't have special meanings in programming, right?  If someone tells you that the issue is that something is INSIDE a loop then the solution should be obvious.  If it's not, think a little bit at least.

Comment: ok . . . . .. . . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If rdr.HasRows Then
    While rdr.Read
        arrName.Add(rdr("numb"))
        For Each pno As String In arrName
            MsgBox(pno)
        Next

    End While
End If
```

to

```
If rdr.HasRows Then
    While rdr.Read
        arrName.Add(rdr("numb"))
    End While
End If
For Each pno As String In arrName
    MsgBox(pno)
Next
```

Comment: the output of the code you give us 639057318820 639057318820 639355514108 639057318820 639355514108 639056784959

Comment: it has the same outcome :(